# Copy from VARCHAR field to NUMBER field such that VARCHAR value becomes null after being copied to NUMBER field

Tags: oracle

I have two tables **Table1** and **Table2** both with the same columns TestResult and Testcounts. **Table1** has testresult as varchar and **Table2** has testresult as number.
I have a string .for eg "Oracle" as value for testresult of varchar type for **Table1** which needs to be inserted to testresult of number type of **Table2** as null.How can i do this? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated :)

## EDIT

I have table1 with columns as TestResult varchar2(50) and Testcount number with values as "0.5","0.6","0.8","Oracle" for TestResult and 1,2,3,4 for Testcount.

Now i have another table Table2 as TestResult number and Testcount number with no values, in other words its empty.. I would like to insert all data from table1 to table2 with "Oracle" being inserted as "null"

Comment: Are any of your `table1` string values for `testresult` convertible to numbers? If not they will all have to become null, which is simple but makes the data in `table2` rather hard to interpret. Or is there just one specific non-convertibel string you want to copy as null? This seems an odd thing to want to do. Representative sample data and expected results might be helpful.

Comment: You don't have to "convert" the varchar to null. Just set that column to `Null`. I think you are overthinking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do what you've asked for:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (TESTRESULT, TESTCOUNTS)
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(TESTRESULT, '[0-9.]*')) = LENGTH(TESTRESULT) THEN TESTRESULT
           ELSE NULL
         END,
         TESTCOUNTS
    FROM TABLE1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d433/3)

Comment: I think you all have misunderstood my question.No worries , i will try to elaborate..

Comment: Please don't use comments to communicate changes to your question. Instead, please **edit the question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and make your changes there. I've done it for you this time. Please keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single string value that you can't convert to a number, and you want to set that to null, you can just use a case expression to supply the null:

```
insert into table2 (testresult, testcounts)
select case when testresult = 'Oracle' then null else to_number(testresult) end,
  testcounts
from table1;
```

Demo:

```
create table table1 (testresult varchar2(10), testcounts number);

insert into table1
select '0.5', 1 from dual
union all select '0.6', 2 from dual
union all select '0.8', 3 from dual
union all select 'Oracle', 4 from dual;

create table table2 (testresult number, testcounts number);

insert into table2 (testresult, testcounts)
select case when testresult = 'Oracle' then null else to_number(testresult) end,
  testcounts
from table1;

select * from table2;

TESTRESULT TESTCOUNTS
---------- ----------
        .5          1
        .6          2
        .8          3
                    4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=540d3c47ccbe0a5893daa38e7c4ecbd9)

If you are using Oracle 12c Release 2 (or above) you could also just try to convert the string to a number and use the `default ... on conversion error` clause to substitute null for that, or any other, non-numeric value:

```
insert into table2 (testresult, testcounts)
select to_number(testresult default null on conversion error), testcounts
from table1;

select * from table2;

TESTRESULT TESTCOUNTS
---------- ----------
        .5          1
        .6          2
        .8          3
                    4
```

In earlier versions you could do the same thing with a user-defined function that wraps the real `to_number()` call and returns null on error. Or a regex/translate check similar to what @BobJarvis has shown.

Having multiple rows with null would make the data hard to interpret though, so hopefully you only have this one fixed value...

Comment: insert into table2 (testresult, testcounts)
select to_number(testresult default null on conversion error), testcounts
from table1;    I am getting  ORA-00907:missing right parenthesis error. Please help Alex :)

Comment: Are you on Oracle 12c Release 2? I forgot that wasn't added in R1.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production  This is my oracle version Alex.. :)

Comment: @G4Gaurab - OK, well I said in the answer that the `default .. on conversion` was 12c only, so that isn't relevant for you. The first statement using a `case` expression will work in 11gR2.

Comment: yes Alex, actually Bob's answer worked for me..Case Expression is good only for specific value as you mentioned. Anyways, Thank you for all those information. Appreciated !!!

Comment: @G4Gaurab - right, that's what you said you had. If you have multiple values that you need to go to null you can list them all in the case expression, or if you don't know what they are then you can use your own function to convert to numbers as I mentioned, but Bob's approach is good too. I still question how useful the data is with multiple null values though as you don't know what the counts relate to. But it's your data *8-)